# Issue while setting up tls/ssl for mongo db connection in a spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to setup mongodb connection settings for a spring boot application which needs ssl settings enabled and a .pem file.
My application.yml file looks like

```
 spring:
      data:
        mongodb:
          uri: mongodb://user:Pass@host:37017/DEV?authSource=admin&tls=true&tlsCAFile=path to .pem
    file      
          database: DEV
```

I am using spring mongodb-driver-core of 4.6.1 version.

But I get the following error

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:684)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:555)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:329)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateStatus$CertificateStatusConsumer.consume(CertificateStatus.java:295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Maybe test with openssl, the URI would correspond to `openssl s_client -connect host:37017 -CAfile "path to .pem file" -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q` What is the config file of the MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Java Client requires the certificate be loaded in the JVM keystore.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved if you have pem bundled(like aws document db).

1. Place the pem file in src/main/resources, so it will be copied to
   jar by build system. For aws document db this file is available from aws global-bundle.pem
2. In application properties set these two properties

   spring.data.mongodb.ssl.bundle=awscert
   spring.ssl.bundle.pem.awscert.truststore.certificate=classpath:global-bundle.pem

Reference for settingup bundle [Spring boot security ssl bundles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-ssl-bundles)